# JQuery xml each fires without element

Tags: jquery, xml, each

I'm facing this strange JQuery behaviour. Given an xml string with a list of ids which is empty, the each loop fires nevertheless:

```
var xmltext = '<xml><ids></ids></xml>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmltext);
var xml = $(xmlDoc);
traverse(xml);

function traverse(xml) {
    if (xml != null) {
        $('ids', xml).each(function (index) {
            // why do I get here??
            var id = $('id', this).first().text();  // id is ""!
            doSomething(id);
        });
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: I did miss a stupid bug, sorry.
Here is what it should be:

```
function traverse(xml) {
    $('ids', xml).each(function (index) {
        var self = $(this);
        $('id', self).each(function (index) {
            var id = $(this).text();
            doSomething(id);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: If the tag exists ...the `each` will run ... even if there is only one. And you have such a tag

Comment: But it has none. It would, if it was `<ids><id>1</id></ids>`, but there is no such `id` element at all, so I would expect no `each`.

Comment: But the `each` is on `$('ids')` not `$('id')` and there definitely is a `<ids>` tag

Comment: doh, I knew I was stuck on the wrong path, you are perfectly right, sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that the callback should fire only for *non-empty* `id` tags.

This is not the case; the jQuery selector selects the `id` tags. You make no stipulation of their needing to be non-empty. If that's what you mean, then:

```
$('ids:not(:empty)', xml).each(...
```

Comment: Note that `:empty` will not filter out element if there is any whitespace inside tag

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming the elements are, as shown in his source XML, genuinely empty.

Comment: Please accept an answer if you deem one to have answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if xml is null , however the presence of ids does not make it so , working code

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3ksvy65p/

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmltext);
var xml = $(xmlDoc);
traverse(xml);

function traverse(xml) {
    if ($('ids').length != 0) {
        $('ids', xml).each(function (index) {
        alert();
            // why do I get here??
            var id = $('id', this).first().text();  // id is ""!
            doSomething(id);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: sure xml is not null, but the 'ids' list should be empty, so I didn't expect `each` to fire on an empty object (or array). Actually I read somewhere else here that it shouldn't (and it still makes no sense to me). But thanks for the answer, so I will have to check for such empty lists everywhere now :-(